# dropdown menu html code with select options from django

Tags: html, django, drop-down-menu

My HTML code is below:

```
<select name="txn" tabindex="3" id="txn" class="fixed" onfocus="highlightInput(this.id)" onblur="unhighlightInput(this.id)">
    <option value="RR" my="{{txn|genselected:"RR"|safe}>RR</option>
    <option value="CR" my="{{txn|genselected:"CR"|safe}}">CR</option>
    <option value="SR" my="{{txn|genselected:"SR"|safe}}">SR</option>
    <option value="OR" my="{{txn|genselected:"OR"|safe}}">OR</option>
</select>
```

txn is defined in forms.py as:

txn = forms.ChoiceField(label="txn", choices = it_const.TXN),

My Question:
The option values are dynamically increasing in the database? i Want to read the option values from the database and put them in dropdown menu in html. Can you please help me with HTML code and how to read the options from txn form field and display it in menu options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

views

```
def view_name(request):
    form = OptionForm()
    options = Option.objects.filter()
    return render(request, 'page.html', {
        'form': form, 
        'options': options,
    })
```

html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}    
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% for option in options %}
<p>{{option.field}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this is not in select->option as the question. How to render not <p> but <select><option> instead? Like in case of a dropdown menu...

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the database values in the view file, and then add them to an array, and then render the array as option for form field.

```
TXN_choices = Options.objects.all()

#and then run a for loop to dynamically generate the options array:
TXN = (
        ('x', 'xxx'),
        ('y', 'yyyy'),
    )

and then render the ModelForm.
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your response. I am now seeing TXN in the html (TXN is populated in view). I print it using {{TXN}} in html code and its printing (('x', 'xxx'), ('y', 'yyy'))... How do i populate these values in the dropdown options?

Comment: don't send the TXN variable directly to the HTML response. populate this TXN variable right above the definition if your model form, and that's all. On runtime, it will directly populate the TXN inside the models.py/forms.py, and while rendering it, it will use those values.